# How to: write nice HTML code and Javascript console

Tags: javascript, html, console, whitespace

This is not a question to make any code work, but more an issue of OCD :-)

If I have this code:

`<div id="div1">The text above has been created dynamically.</div>`

and in my JavaScript I write this:

`var div1 = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
console.log(div1);`

Then I get this output in the browser:
`"The text above has been created dynamically."`

But when I do this in my HTML:

`<div id="div1">
    The text above has been created dynamically.
</div>`

Then I get this in my console:

`"
            The text above has been created dynamically.
        "`

You can see there is a huge gap.
Now in my actual webpage it makes no difference, but I like tidy code :-)
So as far as I can tell I can't have tidy html and a tidy javascript console output.

Am I correct in this or can I change this?
I know it seems a petty thing, but I would like to remove the unnecessary spaces in my console if I can.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `console.log(div1.innerHTML.trim())`?

Comment: Because that is what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Make an answer and I can accept it - unless there is a reason why trim() shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could accomplish what you're looking for (prettier logging) with [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
console.log(div1.innerHTML.trim());
```